# Shapely Polygon From CSV Coordinates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, shapely

So I've read in a .csv file with pandas. I'm looking to read a specific row and column that has the coordinates of a polygon available. It looks like this `"(-117.878472193291,33.9258862905858),(-117.959630976464,33.9287353414733),(-117.988036550575,33.8445186678524),(-117.871292762472,33.8478889307759)"`.

Now I want to convert that into an actual polygon I can use with Shapely.

My code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(thecsv.csv)

print(df['coodinates'].iloc[:1])
```

```
display: 0    (-117.878472193291,33.9258862905858),(-117.959...
```

I try to convert that to a polygon with:

```
poly = Polygon(df['coordinates'].iloc[:1])
```

Now I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples

Any suggestions? Am I going about this correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coordinates seem to be in a Python literal like syntax. You can parse it using `ast.literal_eval` before passing it to `Polygon`:

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

df["coordinates"] = df["coordinates"].apply(lambda c: Polygon(ast.literal_eval(c)))

print(df)
```

a.csv:

```
coordinates
"(-117.878472193291,33.9258862905858),(-117.959630976464,33.9287353414733),(-117.988036550575,33.8445186678524),(-117.871292762472,33.8478889307759)"
```

Output:

```
                                         coordinates
0  POLYGON ((-117.878472193291 33.9258862905858, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the conversion but it returns a new error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_geom'"

Comment: What are you running when you get that AttributeError?